# PHP .csv file overwriting

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I've been writing a registration system with PHP which works via command-line. And I've faced a problem with overwriting text. I want to save all data not replace the old one. How can this problem be solved?

```
function addUser($username, $lastname, $mobile, $mobile2, $comment) {
    $myArray = [$username, $lastname, $mobile, $mobile2, $comment];
    $myFileString = implode(':', $myArray);
    $myDataArray = [];
    array_push($myDataArray, $myFileString);
    $myFile = fopen("users.csv", "w+");
    foreach ($myDataArray as $line) {
    fputcsv($myFile,explode(',',$line));
    }
    fclose($myFile);
    echo $myFile;
}
```

Comment: Ok do you mind telling us what the problem is or are we going to guess?

Comment: As i mentioned. Every time i add new text the old one dissapears. I want to collect all data.

Comment: You didn't mention anything.

Comment: Meh My bad, I`ll change the topic name which will be more clearly for other people

Comment: Problem is just with your mode "w+", File pointer should be at the end when you write new text, find a fopen mode in which file pointer jumps to the end as soon as you open a file. Hope this helps to clear your concept on csv or any file operations.

Comment: I have another question. After selecting number 2 in my command line i see all elements which are in .csv file. Elements inside array have key [0], [1]....  So does my 'Array' also have key?
else if($inputas == 2) {
                
                if (file_exists('users.csv') == false) { 
                    echo 'text';
                } else {
                echo 'Duomenys esantys faile: ' . "\n";
                $myFile = fopen("users.csv","r");
                while(!feof($myFile)) {
                    print_r(fgetcsv($myFile));
                 }

Answer (score 3):

Open the file for *appending* instead of for *writing*:

```
$myFile = fopen("users.csv", "a+");
```

From [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() only affects the reading position, writes are always appended.